# Display attributes for created features disappear upon exiting "Edit"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes

I have a very simple map with a land grid. After adding a new polygon, the symbology shows up appropriately, and remains through Save Edits, but disappears as soon as I hit Stop Editing. The polygon remains, both visibly (if I select it) and in the Attribute Table, but the symbology changes to blank, and will only show up if I check "All Other Values" in the Symbology tab.

Things I have tried, to no avail:

1. Copy/pasting the value within the field from a polygon that shows up correctly into the appropriate field of the new polygon. Polygons with correct symbology have blank fields. I've also tried deleting anything that might have gotten into the field (spaces..?).
2. Many of the suggestions on this post: [Created features disappear when saving edits?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287480/created-features-disappear-when-saving-edits), including checking Feature Exclusions, and there are no Definition Queries.
3. Copy/pasting the Attributes from one "good" polygon to the "bad" polygon. It changes the symbology to the correct color, keeps it after Save Edit, and then reverts after Stopping Editing.
4. Delete feature templates, and then create one using a "good" polygon that shows up as expected. Use that template to draw a new polygon. Same result, stays through Save Edit, disappears after Stop Editing.
5. Copy/paste a "good" polygon, then use Editor to Move Vertices over to where I want the new polygon to be.

Also, the color/symbology doesn't seem to disappear until I zoom out. But when I zoom back in, it doesn't reappear. I don't have any extents set on this layer.

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop, and I am very much a beginner (I know how to navigate, but my vocabulary is terrible).

Comment: If this is shapefiles delete associated sbn and sbx files in explorer.

Comment: Also check spatial extent in environment setting, union of inputs should work.

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007161 has a few pointers. I would make a copy (in a zip file) and follow the recommendations by @FelixIP. Another trick that might work is to create a new file geodatabase, import the shapefile by right clicking on the database and choose import features, then if you really need a shapefile export it back to a shapefile. The .sbn and .sbx files are indices which are rebuilt when importing into a geodatabase, a shapefile can live without these and also .cpg (codepage), .prj (projection) and any .xml files without breaking too much.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. To clarify, @FelixIP, when you say delete associated sbn and sbx files in explorer, you mean Windows Explorer? Then reconnect Source data to the shapefile after those have been deleted?

Comment: After much further tinkering, I think it was somehow related to what was IN the field that the symbology was based on... should have been blank like the others, but somehow wasn't. When I changed ALL blank fields (including new polygon) to a text-based acronym, it worked correctly. Thanks to you both (@FelixIP & @Michael Stimson) for suggestions -- I learned some things I didn't know before!!

Comment: Yes this is what I suggest. Close app, delete files, open app